# Parse Play by Play Sports Data - Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have text that looks like the following (at bottom).  It is play by play data for football.  I am making a function to get data out of this text, based on two arguments, the quarter, and minutes played in the quarter.  So if the function gets passed `quarter=q2, time=10` I have to grab all of the text from the beginning until I get the play recorded in the 2nd quarter at 10 minute mark.  The problem is that there may not be a timestamp to locate with 10 minutes for the 2nd quarter.  So the regex would keep looking until the 3rd or forth quarter... Another problem is that if there is no timestamp in the 2nd quarter for 10, the correct behaviour is to grab all the text until a timestamp of 9, then 8, etc.

I could do this by splitting up the play by play data into four text variables, one for each quarter (the 4th quarter would include overtime).  Then I could make a regex to find the plays in the given quarter at the right time, and stick that inside a loop which will keep adjusting the timestamp until it matches.  Then I can append the text for all previous quarters (for instance just quarter 1, if I'm searching inside the text variable for quarter 2) to the match I found for the indicated quarter.

Is there a better way to do this with some more, "efficient", regex?

```
1st Quarter Play by Play Marshall at 15:00 MRSH MEM

Anthony Binswanger  kickoff for 63 yards returned by  Michael Grandberry  for 23 yards to the Memph 30. 
Memphis at 14:45 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 30 Earnest Williams  rush for 12 yards to the Memph 42 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 42 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Duke Calhoun  for 30 yards to the Marsh 28 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 28 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Brett Russell  for 16 yards to the Marsh 12 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 12 Carlton Robinzine  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 11 out-of-bounds. 
2nd and 9 at MRSH 11 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Maurice Jones  for no gain to the Marsh 11. 
3rd and 9 at MRSH 11 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Duke Calhoun  for 3 yards to the Marsh 8. 
4th and 6 at MRSH 8 Matt Reagan  25 yard field goal GOOD. 
Matt Reagan  kickoff for 64 yards returned by  Darius Marshall  for 8 yards to the Marsh 14. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 7 plays 62 yards, 02:12 Memph FG
 Marshall at 12:48 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 14 Darius Marshall  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 15. 
2nd and 9 at MRSH 15 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Emmanuel Spann  for 6 yards to the Marsh 21. 
3rd and 3 at MRSH 21 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Darius Passmore 
4th and 3 at MRSH 21 Anthony Binswanger  punt for 23 yards downed at the Marsh 44. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 3 plays 7 yards, 01:37 Marsh PUNT
 Memphis at 11:11 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 44 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Steven Black 
2nd and 10 at MRSH 44 Joseph Doss  rush for 6 yards to the Marsh 38. 
3rd and 4 at MRSH 38 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Earnest Williams  for 15 yards to the Marsh 23 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 23 Joseph Doss  rush for 3 yards to the Marsh 20. 
2nd and 7 at MRSH 20 Matt Malouf  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 19 out-of-bounds. 
3rd and 6 at MRSH 19 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Brett Russell  for 12 yards to the Marsh 7 for a 1ST down. 
1st and Goal at MRSH 7 Memphis penalty 5 yard false start on Brandon Pearce accepted. 
1st and Goal at MRSH 12 Will Hudgens  rush for a loss of 6 yards to the Marsh 18. 
2nd and Goal at MRSH 18 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Brett Russell 
3rd and Goal at MRSH 18 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Joseph Doss  for 9 yards to the Marsh 9. 
4th and Goal at MRSH 9 Matt Reagan  26 yard field goal GOOD. 
Matt Reagan  kickoff for 64 yards returned by  Darius Marshall  for 17 yards to the Marsh 23. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 10 plays 35 yards, 03:43 Memph FG
 Marshall at 7:19 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 23 Darius Marshall  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 24. 
2nd and 9 at MRSH 24 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 8 yards to the Marsh 32. 
3rd and 1 at MRSH 32 Darius Marshall  rush for 2 yards to the Marsh 34 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 34 Memphis penalty 5 yard offside accepted, no play. 
1st and 5 at MRSH 39 Bernard Morris  sacked by Jada Brown at the Marsh 38 for a loss of 1 yard. 
2nd and 6 at MRSH 38 Bernard Morris  rush for 2 yards to the Marsh 40. 
3rd and 4 at MRSH 40 Bernard Morris  pass intercepted by LeRico Mathis at the Memph 44, returned for 2 yards to the Memph 46. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 6 plays 17 yards, 03:44 Marsh INT
 Memphis at 4:13 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 46 T.J. Pitts  rush for 3 yards to the Memph 49. 
2nd and 7 at MEM 49 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Duke Calhoun  for 10 yards to the Marsh 41 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 41 T.J. Pitts  rush for 4 yards to the Marsh 37. 
2nd and 6 at MRSH 37 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlos Singleton 
3rd and 6 at MRSH 37 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlos Singleton 
4th and 6 at MRSH 37 Matt Malouf  punt for 31 yards downed at the Marsh 6. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 5 plays 17 yards, 01:36 Memph PUNT
 Marshall at 2:08 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 6 Darius Marshall  rush for 9 yards to the Marsh 15 out-of-bounds. 
2nd and 1 at MRSH 15 Darius Marshall  rush for 7 yards to the Marsh 22 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 22 Chubb Small  rush for 9 yards to the Marsh 31. 
2nd and 1 at MRSH 31 Chubb Small  rush for 8 yards to the Marsh 39 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 39 Darius Marshall  rush for 3 yards to the Marsh 42. 
End of 1st Quarter 
2nd Quarter Play by Play Marshall at 15:00 MRSH MEM
2nd and 7 at MRSH 42 Darius Marshall  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 43. 
3rd and 6 at MRSH 43 Bernard Morris  rush for 4 yards to the Marsh 47. 
4th and 2 at MRSH 47 Anthony Binswanger  punt for 40 yards, returned by  Earnest Williams  for 4 yards to the Memph 17. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 7 plays 41 yards, 03:00 Marsh PUNT
 Memphis at 14:08 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 17 T.J. Pitts  rush for 4 yards to the Memph 21. 
2nd and 6 at MEM 21 T.J. Pitts  rush for 6 yards to the Memph 27 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 27 T.J. Pitts  rush for 4 yards to the Memph 31. 
2nd and 6 at MEM 31 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Maurice Jones  for 7 yards to the Memph 38 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 38 T.J. Pitts  rush for 1 yard to the Memph 39. 
2nd and 9 at MEM 39 Joseph Doss  rush for a loss of 1 yard to the Memph 38. 
3rd and 10 at MEM 38 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Duke Calhoun 
4th and 10 at MEM 38 Brent Sutherland  punt for 41 yards, returned by  Bryant Milligan  for 13 yards to the Marsh 34. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 7 plays 21 yards, 03:47 Memph PUNT
 Marshall at 10:21 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 34 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Emmanuel Spann  for 25 yards to the Memph 41 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 41 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Marshall  for 7 yards to the Memph 34. 
2nd and 3 at MEM 34 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Cody Slate  for 4 yards to the Memph 30 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 30 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Chubb Small  for no gain to the Memph 30. 
2nd and 10 at MEM 30 Bernard Morris  rush for 5 yards to the Memph 25. 
3rd and 5 at MEM 25 Memphis penalty 5 yard offside on Freddie Barnett accepted, no play. 
1st and 10 at MEM 20 Timeout MARSHALL, clock 06:57. 
1st and 10 at MEM 20 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Cody Slate  for 20 yards for a TOUCHDOWN. 
Anthony Binswanger  extra point GOOD. 
Anthony Binswanger  kickoff for 69 yards returned by  Michael Grandberry  for 29 yards to the Memph 30. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 6 plays 66 yards, 03:29 Marsh TD
 Memphis at 6:52 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 30 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Steven Black  for 13 yards to the Memph 43 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 43 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Earnest Williams  for 9 yards to the Marsh 48. 
2nd and 1 at MRSH 48 Joseph Doss  rush for 2 yards to the Marsh 46 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 46 Matt Malouf  rush for 5 yards to the Marsh 41. 
2nd and 5 at MRSH 41 Matt Malouf  rush for 3 yards to the Marsh 38. 
3rd and 2 at MRSH 38 Joseph Doss  rush for 3 yards to the Marsh 35 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 35 Joseph Doss  rush for 3 yards to the Marsh 32. 
2nd and 7 at MRSH 32 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlos Singleton , broken up by Zearrick Matthews. 
3rd and 7 at MRSH 32 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Dave Thomas 
4th and 7 at MRSH 32 Timeout MEMPHIS, clock 03:12. 
4th and 7 at MRSH 32 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlton Robinzine , broken up by Zearrick Matthews. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 10 plays 38 yards, 03:46 Memph DOWNS
 Marshall at 3:06 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 32 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Darius Marshall 
2nd and 10 at MRSH 32 Marshall penalty 10 yard holding on Brian Leggett accepted, no play. 
2nd and 20 at MRSH 22 Bernard Morris  rush for 4 yards to the Marsh 26. 
3rd and 16 at MRSH 26 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Cody Slate 
4th and 16 at MRSH 26 Anthony Binswanger  punt for 51 yards, returned by  Earnest Williams  for a loss of 3 yards to the Memph 20. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 3 plays -6 yards, 01:11 Marsh PUNT
 Memphis at 1:55 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 20 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Joseph Doss  for 3 yards to the Memph 23. 
2nd and 7 at MEM 23 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Steven Black  for 10 yards to the Memph 33 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 33 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Steven Black 
2nd and 10 at MEM 33 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Dave Thomas 
3rd and 10 at MEM 33 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Carlton Robinzine  for 37 yards to the Marsh 30 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 30 Joseph Doss  rush for a loss of 1 yard to the Marsh 31. 
2nd and 11 at MRSH 31 Timeout MEMPHIS, clock 00:39. 
2nd and 11 at MRSH 31 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Earnest Williams  for 11 yards to the Marsh 20 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 20 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Steven Black  for 7 yards to the Marsh 13. 
2nd and 3 at MRSH 13 Team pass incomplete. 
3rd and 3 at MRSH 13 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete. 
4th and 3 at MRSH 13 Matt Reagan  30 yard field goal GOOD. 
Matt Reagan  kickoff for 50 yards returned by  Darius Marshall  for 33 yards to the Memph 47. 
End of 2nd Quarter 

3rd Quarter Play by Play Memphis at 15:00 MRSH MEM

Matt Reagan  kickoff for 62 yards returned by  Darius Marshall  for 23 yards to the Marsh 31. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 1 play 0 yards, 00:04 Marsh END
 HALF Marshall at 15:00 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 31 Bernard Morris  rush for 10 yards to the Marsh 41 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 41 Darius Marshall  rush for 9 yards to the 50 yard line. 
2nd and 1 at MEM 50 Darius Marshall  rush for 15 yards to the Memph 35 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 35 Chubb Small  rush for 12 yards to the Memph 23 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 23 Chubb Small  rush for 7 yards to the Memph 16. 
2nd and 3 at MEM 16 Darius Marshall  rush for 5 yards to the Memph 11 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 11 Darius Marshall  rush for 11 yards for a TOUCHDOWN. 13 
Anthony Binswanger  extra point GOOD. 14 
Anthony Binswanger  kickoff for 63 yards returned by  Michael Grandberry  for 17 yards to the Memph 14, Memphis penalty 10 yard illegal block on Tyler Griffin accepted. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 7 plays 69 yards, 02:58 Marsh TD
 Memphis at 12:02 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 14 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlton Robinzine 
14 
2nd and 10 at MEM 14 Joseph Doss  rush for 4 yards to the Memph 18. 
3rd and 6 at MEM 18 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Duke Calhoun  for 23 yards to the Memph 41 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 41 Joseph Doss  rush for 1 yard to the Memph 42. 
2nd and 9 at MEM 42 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Carlos Singleton  for 8 yards to the 50 yard line. 
3rd and 1 at MEM 50 T.J. Pitts  rush for no gain to the 50 yard line. 
4th and 1 at MEM 50 Joseph Doss  rush for 2 yards to the Marsh 48 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 48 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Maurice Jones  for 37 yards to the Marsh 11 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 11 Matt Malouf  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 10. 
2nd and 9 at MRSH 10 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Brett Russell  for a loss of 7 yards, fumbled at the Marsh 19, recovered by Memph at the Marsh 19. 
3rd and 18 at MRSH 19 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Carlos Singleton  for 19 yards for a TOUCHDOWN. 

Two-point conversion attempt, Will Hudgens pass to Carlos Singleton GOOD. 

Matt Reagan  kickoff for 66 yards returned by  Darius Marshall  for 25 yards to the Marsh 29. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 11 plays 86 yards, 05:10 Memph TD
 Marshall at 6:52 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 29 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  E.J. Wynn  for 7 yards to the Marsh 26, Marshall penalty 10 yard holding on Bryant Milligan accepted. 
 1st and 13 at MRSH 26 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Brian Shope  for 9 yards to the Marsh 35. 
2nd and 4 at MRSH 35 Darius Marshall  rush for 9 yards to the Marsh 44 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 44 Chubb Small  rush for 4 yards to the Marsh 48. 
2nd and 6 at MRSH 48 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  E.J. Wynn  for 2 yards to the 50 yard line. 
3rd and 4 at MEM 50 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Chubb Small  for 10 yards to the Memph 40 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MEM 40 Darius Marshall  rush for 7 yards to the Memph 33. 
2nd and 3 at MEM 33 Darius Marshall  rush for 9 yards to the Memph 24 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 24 Darius Marshall  rush for 1 yard, fumbled at the Memph 23, recovered by Quinton McCrary at the Memph 23. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 9 plays 48 yards, 03:51 Marsh FUMB
 Memphis at 3:01 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 23 Earnest Williams  rush for 3 yards to the Memph 26. 
 2nd and 7 at MEM 26 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Earnest Williams  for 12 yards to the Memph 38 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MEM 38 T.J. Pitts  rush for 6 yards to the Memph 44. 
2nd and 4 at MEM 44 T.J. Pitts  rush for 13 yards to the Marsh 43 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 43 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Carlos Singleton  for 3 yards to the Marsh 40. 
2nd and 7 at MRSH 40 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Duke Calhoun 
3rd and 7 at MRSH 40 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Carlos Singleton  for 35 yards to the Marsh 5 for a 1ST down. 
1st and Goal at MRSH 5 T.J. Pitts  rush for 1 yard to the Marsh 4 out-of-bounds. 
End of 3rd Quarter 
4th Quarter Play by Play Memphis at 15:00 MRSH MEM
 2nd and Goal at MRSH 4 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Greg Hinds  for 4 yards for a TOUCHDOWN. 

Matt Reagan  extra point GOOD. 

Matt Reagan  kickoff for 69 yards returned by  Emmanuel Spann  for 23 yards to the Marsh 24. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 9 plays 77 yards, 02:44 Memph TD
 Marshall at 14:55 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 24 Bernard Morris  rush for 12 yards to the Marsh 36 for a 1ST down. 
 1st and 10 at MRSH 36 Chubb Small  rush for 22 yards to the Memph 27 for a 1ST down, Memphis penalty 15 yard face mask on Will Hudgens accepted. 
1st and 10 at MEM 27 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 15 yards to the Memph 12 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 12 Chubb Small  rush for a loss of 2 yards to the Memph 14. 
2nd and 12 at MEM 14 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Cody Slate  for 6 yards to the Memph 8 out-of-bounds. 
3rd and 6 at MEM 8 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Courtney Edmonson 
4th and 6 at MEM 8 Emmanuel Spann  rush for a loss of 8 yards to the Memph 16. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 7 plays 60 yards, 02:38 Marsh DOWNS
 Memphis at 12:17 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 16 T.J. Pitts  rush for 7 yards to the Memph 23. 
 2nd and 3 at MEM 23 T.J. Pitts  rush for 2 yards to the Memph 25. 
3rd and 1 at MEM 25 Matt Malouf  rush for 2 yards to the Memph 27 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 27 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Carlos Singleton  for 4 yards to the Memph 31. 
2nd and 6 at MEM 31 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Duke Calhoun  for 2 yards to the Memph 33. 
3rd and 4 at MEM 33 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Maurice Jones  for 3 yards to the Memph 36. 
4th and 1 at MEM 36 Timeout MEMPHIS, clock 08:04. 
4th and 1 at MEM 36 Brent Sutherland  punt for 33 yards punt out-of-bounds at the Marsh 31. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 6 plays 20 yards, 04:13 Memph PUNT
 Marshall at 8:04 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 31 Bernard Morris  sacked by Josh Weaver at the Marsh 24 for a loss of 8 yards. 
 2nd and 17 at MRSH 24 Bernard Morris  rush for 13 yards to the Marsh 37. 
3rd and 4 at MRSH 37 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 14 yards to the Memph 49 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 49 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Chubb Small 
2nd and 10 at MEM 49 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Emmanuel Spann  for 20 yards to the Memph 29 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 29 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Cody Slate  for 11 yards to the Memph 18 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 18 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 5 yards to the Memph 13 out-of-bounds. 
2nd and 5 at MEM 13 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Shawn Lauzon  for 9 yards to the Memph 4 for a 1ST down. 
1st and Goal at MEM 4 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Bryant Milligan 
2nd and Goal at MEM 4 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete to  Emmanuel Spann 
3rd and Goal at MEM 4 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 4 yards for a TOUCHDOWN. 

Anthony Binswanger  extra point GOOD. 

Anthony Binswanger  kickoff for 60 yards returned by  Michael Grandberry  for 14 yards to the Memph 24, fumbled at the Memph 24, recovered by Memph. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 11 plays 69 yards, 02:35 Marsh TD
 Memphis at 5:22 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 24 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Duke Calhoun  for 6 yards to the Memph 30. 
 2nd and 4 at MEM 30 Marshall penalty 15 yard pass interference on Zearrick Matthews accepted, no play. 
1st and 10 at MEM 45 T.J. Pitts  rush for 4 yards to the Memph 49. 
2nd and 6 at MEM 49 Will Hudgens  pass complete to  Maurice Jones  for 7 yards to the Marsh 44 for a 1ST down out-of-bounds. 
1st and 10 at MRSH 44 T.J. Pitts  rush for 2 yards to the Marsh 42. 
2nd and 8 at MRSH 42 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlton Robinzine 
3rd and 8 at MRSH 42 Will Hudgens  pass incomplete to  Carlton Robinzine 
4th and 8 at MRSH 42 Timeout MEMPHIS, clock 02:34. 
4th and 8 at MRSH 42 Memphis penalty delay of game declined. 
4th and 8 at MRSH 42 Brent Sutherland  punt for 42 yards for a touchback. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Memph drive: 6 plays 34 yards, 02:56 Memph PUNT
 Marshall at 2:34 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MRSH 20 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 11 yards to the Marsh 31 for a 1ST down. 
 1st and 10 at MRSH 31 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Cody Slate  for 9 yards to the Marsh 40 out-of-bounds. 
2nd and 1 at MRSH 40 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Darius Passmore  for 12 yards to the Memph 48 for a 1ST down. 
1st and 10 at MEM 48 Bernard Morris  pass complete to  Cody Slate  for 6 yards to the Memph 42 out-of-bounds. 
2nd and 4 at MEM 42 Team rush for a loss of 19 yards to the Marsh 39. 
3rd and 23 at MRSH 39 Bernard Morris  rush for 20 yards to the Memph 41. 
4th and 3 at MEM 41 Timeout MARSHALL, clock 01:04. 
4th and 3 at MEM 41 Bernard Morris  pass incomplete. 
DRIVE TOTALS: Marsh drive: 7 plays 39 yards, 01:30 Marsh DOWNS
 Memphis at 1:04 MRSH MEM
 1st and 10 at MEM 41 Team rush for a loss of 1 yard to the Memph 40. 
 2nd and 11 at MEM 40 Team rush for a loss of 1 yard to the Memph 39. 
End of 4th Quarter
```

Comment: Why not just read it all into a data structure and store numbers instead of text, then it'll be just trivial to loop through it.

Comment: it took me days of work to realize the wisdom of what you say paul

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not the best way to do it, but if you're sure data will come in exactly this format, this (sloppy) code should work:

```
>>> commentary = #your commentary text
>>>
>>> # Returns the string up to the timestamp.                                                                                                                                         
... # quarter is an int, 1-4, time is int, 0-15.                                                                                                                     
... def getPlayByPlay(commentary, quarter, time):
...     reString = r'\w\w Quarter' #1st Quarter, 2nd Quarter, etc.
...     quarterDex = re.search(str(quarter) + reString, commentary).start()
...     endQuarterDex = 0
...     if quarter == 4:
...         endQuarterDex = len(commentary)
...     else:
...         endQuarterDex = re.search(str(quarter + 1) + reString, commentary).start()
...     for match in re.finditer(r'at \d\d:\d\d', commentary[quarterDex:endQuarterDex]):
...         matchTime = int(match.group(0)[3:5])
...         print matchTime
...         if matchTime < time:
...             return commentary[:quarterDex + match.start()]
...     return commentary[:endQuarterDex]
>>> getPlayByPlay(commentary, 1, 3)
'\n1st Quarter Play by Play ... End of 1st Quarter \n'
>>> getPlayByPlay(commentary, 1, 13)
'\n1st Quarter Play by Play ... 02:12 Memph FG\n Marshall '
>>> getPlayByPlay(commentary, 4, 0)
gives the whole string
```

As you can see, there is NO ERROR CHECKING, and this is completely dependent on the patterns I found in this one specific example. This will crash or return incorrectly if quarter is not an `int` between 1 and 4 or time is not and `int` between 0 and 15. Make sure you notice that `time` is an int (no decimals) -- you could do more sophisticated analysis if necessary. Hope it's helpful!